# I am misunderstanding something fundamental about limit points

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, definition, limits-colimits

Using the definition of limit points which is as follows:

"Consider $A\subset(X,T)$(a topological space with standard topology), $x\in X$ is a limit point of $A$ if for all $U\in T$ s.t. $x\in U$ we have that the intersection of U and A contains a point other than x itself"

I wanted to work out the limit points of $(0,1)$ (I know they are the set $[0,1]$ from the sequence definition of limit points).

I'm having a little confusion using the definition I mentioned above though , here's my problem.

all $U\in T$ are of the form (a,b), now suppose $x\in (a,b)$ and that $a<0<1<b$. Suppose that $x=-2$ for instance and that $(a,b)=(-3,4)$.

So we have found an open set which x is in , and whose intersection with $(0,1)$ is equal to $(0,1)$, clearly this contains many points other than x.

So my question is why is say $x=-2$ not a limit point (according to this definition )?

Comment: It has to be true for *all* $U$.

Comment: Assuming $X = \mathbb{R}$ under the standard topology, another thing to note is that not all open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are open intervals.

Comment: @saulspatz I'm still confused though , considering it for all U, then we have 4 possibilities, 1) a<0<1<b, 2)0<a<1<b 3)a<0<b<1 4) a=0, b=1. But if say $x=a+\epsilon$, then the intersection of (0,1) with (a,b) (where $x \in (a,b) $) will always contain points other than x for all four cases but say for case 1) with x<0  then I have the same problem understanding that I mentioned. Would you mind elaborating just a little please ?

Comment: When $X=(0,1)$ it is NOT true that all $U\in T$ are of the form $(a,b)$.... Every $U\in T$ is the union of a family of sets, each of which is of the form $(a,b).$  For example $(1/4,1/2)\cup (3/4,1)$ and $(0,1)\setminus \{2^{-n}: n\in \Bbb Z^+\}$ are members of $T.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the open interval $U=(-2.1,-1.9).$  It contains $-2$ but does not intersect $(0,1)$.  This shows that $-2$ is not a limit point of $(0,1)$.  $U$ does not contain *any* point of $(0,1)$, let alone a point different from $-2$.